# How to highlight entire table cell on hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a tiny issue where in my table I have gotten the entire TD clickable, and even managed to get the td:hover to work.

However I've come across a point where I need to have blocks that say "Incomplete" (because I don't know how to hide cells without messing up the block sizes). How can I fix it where the entire cell highlights but doesn't highlight the Incomplete ones?

```css
td a:hover {
  background: #c2ceb5;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
td a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
td {
  position: relative;
}
td a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table align="" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff; background-color: #5e913f;" class="mceEditable" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" height="207.75" width="1060">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
                <a class="" title="Super" href="http://handlingmod.jimdo.com/vehicle-list/super/adder/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Adder</span></a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
                <a class="" title="Super" href="http://handlingmod.jimdo.com/vehicle-list/super/vacca/"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Vacca</span></a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
                <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
                <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
               <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
               <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
               <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
              <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
               <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 250px;">
             <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 0px;">
               <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center; border: 5px solid #ffffff; width: 0px;">
               <span style="color: #dddddd;">Uncomplete</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>
    <span style="color: #ffffff;">&#160;</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Will text ever need to wrap within your cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works - http://jsfiddle.net/2pfL7toz/

```
td {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px; /*a bit hacky but works*/
}
td a, td span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
td a:hover {
    background: #c2ceb5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/83ct21vn/3/)?

CSS:

```
td a:hover {
    background: #c2ceb5;
    display: block;
}
td a, td span {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    display: block;
    padding-top:20px;
}
td {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Note:** This solution degrades slightly if your text wraps within a cell.

Comment: Edited solution to degrade less badly when text wraps

Comment: This works nicely! Text isn't centered correctly though, it seems.

Comment: @Matthew No? If not, it should only be a matter of adjusting padding-top.

Comment: @Pangloss Thanks! I up-voted yours, as well. Suggestion taken.